# Object keys to an array. Peculiar approach

Tags: javascript

Suppose, we have an object

```
var obj = { name:'Alex', password:'12345' };
```

I know that I can get array of object's keys as follow:

```
var arr = [];
for(i in obj) { arr.push(i) }; // arr is equal to [name, password]
```

or

```
var arr = Object.keys(obj); // arr is equal to [name, password]
```

But today I saw this code:

```
var arr = [], i = 0;
for (arr[i++] in obj);  // arr is also equal to [name, password]
```

and it makes no sense for me... I'm quite new to `JS`. Can someone explain how does it works?

Comment: Like `i in obj`, `i` is assigned the value of current property key, similarly `arr[i++]` is assigned the key and `i` is incremented.

Comment: It makes more sense if you write `for(o in obj) { arr.push(o) };` since i is normally used as an int counter

Comment: smart, but `Object.keys(obj);` returns the same without some variables.

Comment: I'm not that new to JS but I've never seen something like that. I did some research and came on this site: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/exploring-javascript-for-in-loops/ Apparently you have two possible forms of the for ... in loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a clever piece of code.

```
var arr = [], i = 0;
for (arr[i++] in obj);
```

Do you know what happens in `for .. in` loop? Follow this:

```
for (a in obj) {
  // every loop, a will have one of the key right?
}
```

Which means, technically, every loop:

```
loop 1:
  a = obj's key 1.
loop 2:
  a = obj's key 2.
// and so on...
```

Now, here `arr` is an array. We have `i` with `0` as it's value.

```
loop 1:
  a[i++] = obj's key 1. // is same as
  a[0] = obj's key 1 and increment i
// and so on...
```

Comment: It should be noted, however, that "really clever" doesn't necessarily mean "good". Good code is easy to understand.

Comment: @Quentin Agreed, this is a **clever way of confusing** people.

Answer (score 1):

How a for in works:

```
for(a in b){//copy the [first,second...] key to a;
 alert(a);
}
alert(a);//a will be the last key
```

Now you can use that to store the keys:

```
for(a[i++] in obj){
//does sth like:increase i, copy the first key of obj to a[i], then loop
```

Answer (score 0):

`for..in` loop assigns atomic value of array to the variable we are using.

In your case it's the `array` element i.e a reference for each `key` in `object` stored as `array` of `keys`.

The below snippet will answer you

```js
var obj = { name:'Alex', password:'12345' };

var arr = [], i = 0;

for (arr[i++] in obj){
  //now arr[i - 1] is assigned with key in obj
  console.log(arr[i-1]); //gives the key
};
```